# Slowness with WMSYS.WM_CONCAT function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When I use the Oracle function WMSYS.WM_CONCAT,it my SQL executes very slowly. How can I speed it up? The query is:

```
SELECT T.A,
       T.B,
       WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(T.C),
       WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(T.D) 
  FROM ( SELECT A,B,C,D FROM TABLE_NAME ) T 
 GROUP BY T.A ,T.B
```

The table contains about two million rows and has indexes on related columns.

Comment: table contains about two million rows,and has index on related columns.

Comment: I don't think it's the reason, but why the totally useless derived table? You could simply write `from table_name t`

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: what are the index contents and their order?

Comment: oracle version is 10.2

Answer (score 1):

On 10.2 the fastest string aggregation method uses `CAST` `COLLECT`, as described in [this oracle-developer.net article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306).

```
 SELECT T.A,
        T.B,
        to_string(cast(collect(T.C) as varchar2_ntt)),
        to_string(cast(collect(T.D) as varchar2_ntt))
FROM  (SELECT A,B,C,D FROM TABLE_NAME) T 
GROUP BY T.A,T.B;
```

Note that `WM_CONCAT` does not work in Express Edition, databases without Workspace Manager installed, and 12c.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A,
    B,
    WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(C) OVER (PARTITION BY A,B) concat_c,
    WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(D) OVER (PARTITION BY A,B) concat_d
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Hopefully you understand that query you suggested and OP's example gives different number of rows?

Comment: My query needs a DISTINCT

Comment: You also need to wrap `concat_c` and `concat_d` with `TO_CHAR` to avoid `ORA-00932: incompatible types`. Still I don't see the reason why analytic function would be more performing than old good group by. Have you done any benchmarks?

Comment: Yaroslav, we havn't been told the datastructure of the table so your statement about having to use to_char isn't neccessarly correct. I havn't done any benchmarks , I was just showning an alternate way of doing things.

Comment: Agree that without knowing OP's version it's hard to say is `TO_CHAR` necessary or not. Just to mention that on versions >=10.2.0.5 and >=11.2.0.2 the output of the function is `CLOB` and your query will return error if not wrapped with above mentioned `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

The lag has been noticeable when using WM_CONCAT.  The simplest solution I know is to simply wrap `to_char()` function around it.  For one report with 2 wm_concats and a listagg, it shorten the run time from 1 minute 13 seconds to 7 second.  Have not test a listagg by itself, but I have the wm_concat and it consistently, and dramatically improves run time.